# Problems installing gcc for cross compiling for ARM

Tags: 13.10, gcc, c++, arm, cross-compilation

I've been trying to install the gcc-arm-linux-fnueabi package, and I've done it a few times by a few different methods but I always seem to be missing the c++ folder in the includes directory.

To install, I used:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

and after the installation completes, I have the arm-linux-gnueabi and arm-linux-gnueabihf folders in my /usr directory. When I go into the /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include folder though, there's no c++ folder as I expect there to be, so headers such as iostream, etc. are missing. Same goes for within the arm-linux-gnueabihf directory.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? Did I miss something, perhaps? I'm fairly new to cross compiling but all the documentation I've studied indicates that there should be a c++ folder among the includes, and without it, my attempts to compile even simple test codes fail, since even the iostream header is not available.

**My machine:**
64bit intel i7 processor, on a Asus N56VZ running Ubuntu 13.10

**Target devices:** Beaglebone (both white and black)

Comment: find / -name "*iostream*" 2>/dev/null

Comment: Hm, around iostream there should be asterixes. Can someone reformat my comment and delete the current one?

Comment: C++ headers would be provided as a dependency of **g++**-arm-linux-gnueabihf rather than gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf I think

Comment: I did try searching for it but I only find the codes for compiling on my PC (under /usr/include/c++) but not the files for cross-compiling for the ARM devices.

Comment: @steeldriver The videos I watched and the documents and blogs I read seemed to indicate that just the gcc would be enough. I just installed the g++ ARM package and I have a folder of c++ dependencies now. I'll give it a try and update back here, thanks

Comment: @steeldriver That seems to have done it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @steeldriver, could you write an answer as your comment solved the OP's pb.